# Math pow function is not working

Tags: java, android

The case `caret` is not working. Maybe my logic is not right. When I give value in `num1` and use power sign, the answer is the same as if I give the `num2` value.

```
        case R.id.caret:
            entry = "^";
            if(num1 == 0) {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString());
                txt1.setText("");
            }
           else if (num2 !=0){
                num2 = 0;
                txt1.setText("");
            }

            break;
        case R.id.equal:
            if (!entry.equals(null)) {
                if (num2 != 0) {  
                    } else if (entry.equals("/")) {
                        txt1.setText("");
                        /* op1 = op1 / op2;*/
                        txt1.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(num1));
                    }
                    else if (entry.equals("^")){
                        num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString());
                        txt1.setText("");

                    }
                    else  {
                        Log.e("Values", num1+"=="+num2);
                        Math.pow(num1, num2);
                        txt1.setText("Result" + Integer.toString(num1));
                    }
                } else {
                    operation();
                }
            }
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Brother no one can understand your question i think. Can you please clarify what you want to achieve ??? and whats the problem. Otherwise your question is floating on the air and we cant grab it

Comment: issue is my ^ math.pow function is not working.

Comment: i am making scientific calculator,but my all operators are working fine except math.pow

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning your result of `pow` to anywhere. You need to return the value to a variable. Here to `num1`. Make it like following. It will work.

```
          else  {
                    Log.e("Values", num1+"=="+num2);
                    double result=Math.pow(num1, num2);
                    txt1.setText("Result: " + result +"");
                }
```

**EDIT:**

parameters to `pow` function should be double value.

and in case `R.id.equal` do following

```
 case R.id.equal:

          if (!entry.equals(null)) {

                 if (num2 != 0 && entry.equals("/")) {
                    txt1.setText("");
                    /* op1 = op1 / op2;*/
                    txt1.setText("Result : " + Integer.toString(num1));
                }
                else if (num2 != 0 && entry.equals("^")){
                    Log.e("Values", num1+"=="+num2);
                    double result=Math.pow(num1, num2);
                    txt1.setText("Result: " + result +"");

                }

            }
            else {
                operation();
            }

            break;
```

Comment: but i use int num1 and int num2... and when i paste this code.. error generate int found. double required

Comment: @farhan This is ANOTHER question. No, wait: It's other **2** questions.

Comment: still same problem. no syntax error. my answer is match with num 1 value.

Comment: why are you doing  `else if (entry.equals("^")){
                        num2 = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText().toString());
                        txt1.setText("");

                    }  ` ??? @farhan

Comment: i m totally new in android.

Comment: ok i try, and kindly help me to make a calculator scientific with easy code in andorid.thanks

Comment: You should search for tutorials on internet. This is not a site where you get answers like this. Here it just helps you solving your problems. good luck man. And dont forget to mark the answer as accepted if it works for you. @farhan